# Testing whether the circumcenter of a cyclic quadrilateral lies inside it

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

For a triangle with sides $a, b, c$ (where $c$ is the biggest side) there is a simple check to see whether it's circumcenter lies inside of it:

$$a^2 + b^2 < c^2$$

Is there such an inequality for a cyclic quadrilateral, given its side lengths $a, b, c, d$ (with longest side $d$)?

Can this be generalized to a cyclic convex $n$-gon?

Comment: If you have points instead of side lengths it is easy.  Just take the two points at the ends of the longest side and any other point.  Check the triangle they create per the above rule.  You are basically checking whether the arc created by the long side that is away from the figure is greater or less than $\pi$. The triangle rule you quote comes from wanting the triangle to be acute.

Comment: It would be interesting if there is a formulaic test in terms of side lengths. First of all, if the  consecutive side lengths are a,b,c,d,  does it matter if we permute the order? E.g. if another quadrilateral has consecutive side lengths a,c,b,d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circumcenter of a triangle is inside the triangle if and only if
$$
(a^2+b^2-c^2)(c^2+a^2-b^2)(b^2+c^2-a^2)\gt0\tag{1}
$$

---

The diagonal with sides $a$ and $b$ on  one side and $c$ and $d$ on the other is
$$
e^2=\frac{\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab}+\frac{c^2+d^2}{cd}}{\frac1{ab}+\frac1{cd}}\tag{2}
$$
Then the circumcenter is inside the quadrilateral if and only if
$$
\hspace{-10pt}\small(a^2+b^2-e^2)(e^2+a^2-b^2)(b^2+e^2-a^2)(c^2+d^2-e^2)(e^2+c^2-d^2)(d^2+e^2-c^2)\lt0\tag{3}
$$
or
$$
a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2\tag{4}
$$
Note that $(4)$ implies equality in $(3)$.

Comment: The condition we are looking for cannot be an equation, as is $(4)$. If $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ admit a cyclic quadrilateral containing the center of the circumcircle then so do four sides obtained by changing   $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ by arbitrary small amounts.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: the inequality $(3)$ does not cover the case that the center is on the diagonal. equation $(4)$ is the case that the center is on the diagonal. Since the diagonal is inside the quadrilateral, we need to include this case.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a, b, c, d$ be the lengths of the sides with $a$ being longest or tied for longest (we will eventually see that if there is a tie then the circumcenter is forced inside the polygon).  Interchanging the order of the sides has no effect on the circumcircle and so WLOG the $a$ and $b$ sides are taken to be adjacent to each other.

Draw the diagonal that separates the $a, b$ sides from the $c, d$ sides.  Let $\theta$ be the angle between the $a$ and $b$ sides, $\theta'$ be the angle between the $c$ and $d$ sides.  Apply the Law of Cosines to the two triangles formed by the diagonal:

$\cos(\theta)=(a^2+b^2-x^2)/(2ab)$

$\cos(\theta')=(c^2+d^2-x^2)/(2cd)$

The two angles are supplementary, therefore their cosines sum to zero and the right sides of the above equations must do the same.  Form that Sun and solve for $x^2$:

$x^2=(ab(c^2+d^2)+cd(a^2+b^2))/(ab+cd)$

The circumcenter is outside the quadrilateral when it is on tge opposite side of the $a$ side from the diagonal we drew above.  That condition is:

$a^2>x^2+b^2$

Substitute for x, work through the algebra and obtain this result for the circumcenter lying outside the quadtilateral:

$a^3-a(b^2+c^2+d^2)-2bcd>0$

Note that if $b$,$c$, or $d$ matches $a$, the left side is forced to be negative, pushing the circumenter inside the polygon.